# Name of the theorem for substituting integer arithmetic with modular arithmetic modulo all primes

Tags: modular-arithmetic, terminology, chinese-remainder-theorem

The following proposition (which I consider true) allows to substitute
(1) the congruence relation in modular arithmetic modulo all prime numbers
with (2) the equality relation in integer arithmetic:
\begin{equation}
    \forall A, B \in \mathbb{Z} :
    ( \; A = B \; \Leftrightarrow \;
    \forall p \in \mathbb{P} : A \equiv B \pmod{p} \; )
\end{equation}
Does this proposition have a name?

Comment: No, there is no need to waste limited namespace on obvious facts (is it not obvious to you that  an integer $n$ is divisible by all primes $\iff n = 0?)\ \ $

Comment: Name magic was very popular in bronze age. The fact that $0$ is the only integer divisible by *all* primes is trivial (I hope).

Comment: It's a case of the Hasse Principle or local-global principle.

Comment: It's modular reflexivity, if you want a description, extended by the infinitude of primes.